# What does "other light" mean in "The Fellowship of the Ring"?

Tags: meaning, j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

This phrase is taken from *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Book II, Chapter 1 "Many Meetings" (page 258):

> The doors were thrown open, and they went across a wide passage and through other doors, and came into a further hall. In it were no tables, but a bright fire was burning in a great hearth between the carven pillars upon either side.
>
> Frodo found himself walking with Gandalf. "This is the Hall of Fire" said the wizard. "Here you will hear many songs and tales—if you can keep awake. But except on high days it usually stands empty and quiet, and people come here who wish for peace, and thought. There is always a fire here, all the year round, but there is little **other light**."

What does "other light" mean here?

Comment: Do the author mean other fires around the main fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gandalf explained to Frodo, they are in the "Hall of Fire", where "a bright fire was burning in a great hearth". Fire can be both a source of heat and a source of light. In this hall, the fire in the hearth is the main source of light; the fire is even described as "bright", emphasizing that it is a source of light. The phrase "little other light" means that there is not much light from other sources.